# To the Power ^ in M (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, m, mashup

I creating a custom column in Power BI

```
= Table.AddColumn(Fact_Sale, "Custom", each 2^[Sale Key] , type number)`
```

I tried using ^ to represent the power operator but got an eerror

I tried to google but the when I search for the power operartor all i get is Power Query (same names making it hard to search)

I found this but thre was nothing for hte power operator
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/operators

how can I do it?

Comment: "I got an error". Which one? Where? Is there a reason it isn't it in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power is implemented as a function, not as an operator.

Number.Power(2, 3) will give you 8

[power](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/number-power)